# Webbrowser table innertext numaric data how show in textbox?

Tags: regex, split, innerhtml, regex-greedy, htmlelements

I have posted my HTML below. In which I want to get the Number value from within my textbox area. I've tried several processes and I'm still not getting any valid solution. Please check my HTML and code snippet, and show me a possible solution.

The number prefix will always stay the same when I refresh the page. However, the last number within the "Number" area will change, but will always contain the "206" as the first 3 digits.  Below is my table example.

```
<table align="center" width="500" border="0">
<tr><td align="center" height="30" style="font-size:medium">See your job Details, adriankdins2f3dd@hotmail.com.</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" style="color:#CC3300"><b>Your Job Information   is:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">
<table>
<tr><td><b>Phone Number:</b> 206-600-9159</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Your AGe:</b> 25</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Email:</b> adriankdins2f3dd@hotmail.com</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Job Title</b> cleaner </td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" height="25">Jobinstruction</td>   
</tr>
<tr><td>
</td></tr>
<tr><td
</td></tr> 
</table>
```

As shown below I am trying this process using listbox but I am not receiving anything.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=<tr><td><b>Phone\s Number:\s?</b>\s?)[206]\s.+?(?=</td></tr>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match match in re.Matches(webBrowser1.DocumentText))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(match.Value);
        }
```

If anyone can give me an idea of how I am able to receive all in the browser window as ("206" + Number) within my list box I would appreciate it. Also, if you can explain the answer verbosely and with good comments I would appreciate it, as I'd like to understand the answer in greater detail as well.

Comment: What text do you need to extract? `206-425-2541`? Is the `<table>` the first table in the document?

Comment: yes I am just want this number in my textbox or listbox

Comment: Good, please see my answer.

Comment: no sir <table> after again available <table>

Comment: I am updated my code again pls check

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HtmlAgilityPack and an XPath query:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
...

HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(htmlText);
HtmlNode doc = html.DocumentNode;

HtmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//table/tr/td/b[starts-with(.,'Phone Number:')]/following::text()[1]");

if (node != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
}
```

Comment: I am using windows application mean browser application in c#

Comment: I am updated my code again pls check also I am using windows application form so need windows application code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any external libraries since you are using a WebBrowser component. You need to get access to the right table (in most cases, the table has a unique id, or you can access it by its index in the resulting array obtained with `GetElementsByTagName`).

You can loop through all tables, rows and cells and check if the `InnerText` starts with `Phone Number:` and then grab the value you need.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\tmp2.html");
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    Application.DoEvents();
HtmlElementCollection bColl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");
var TelNum = string.Empty;
var PersonName = string.Empty;
if (bColl != null && bColl.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement td in bColl)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(td.InnerText) && td.InnerText.StartsWith("Phone Number:"))
            TelNum = td.InnerText.Substring(14).Trim();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(td.InnerText) && td.InnerText.StartsWith("Your Name is "))
            PersonName = td.InnerText.Substring(13).Trim();
    }
}
```

I used `Trim()` just in case someone leaves redundant spaces there.

Comment: I am want number show in my textbox also your code I am try same including textbox but not show anything with not finding phone number show error.

Comment: I am sure your idea 100% good but I am need again help why I am not getting anything!!!

Comment: Please share the whole HTML file, and explain what exactly you cannot do with it.

Comment: I have also updated my answer, now, I am just looping over `td` elements.